# MSMQ causes Windows 8 to crash with a BSOD

Tags: c#, windows-8, msmq

I use Windows 8 Pro, C# and .NET 4.5

I use MSMQ to read or peek or send message on a REMOTE machine but it causes the operating system a BSOD...

Locally there is no problem but only when i try to access remote machine with msmq by code.

The code works perfectly under XP/Seven and Server 2008/2012

Here is a little sample :

```
var messageQueue = new MessageQueue(string.Concat("FormatName:DIRECT=", addressType, ":", _queueServer, @"\private$\", _queueName), false, false, QueueAccessMode.Receive);

messageQueue.Receive() => BSOD!!!
```

Do someone has a fix or an explanation?

Thank you,

Kind Regards.

Comment: That seems like a rather serious bug in MSMQ...unprivileged userland code should never be able to cause a BSoD.

Comment: The BSOD would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!!!

MSMQ 4.0 comes with windows server 2008 and last update for any operating system uses ipv6 by default.
So you have to deactivate the IPV6 to prevent the BSOD under Windows 8
Event in other OS, you have to deactivate it to read remote queue!

Comment: There is no reason that IPv6 supoprt being enabled would cause a crash.  If it was IPv6 being enabled was the cause of the BSOD ( which I doubt ) it would happen on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Hi, the fact is that when i activate IPV6 on my Windows 8 and read a remote queue, it crash my pc. 
And when i deactivate it, it runs without problems.

Comment: Without the BSOD error code you cannot rule out the crash is because of a bad driver or some other reason which is only prevented from happening because IPv6.  As I pointed out the problem should exist in Windows Server 2012 but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

If you go into C:\windows\minidump

then open the *.dmp file with "Debugging tools for Windows"

that should give more insight into the nature of the issue.

Comment: I never used this... How can i use these tool to find the bug?!

Comment: So you'll go here   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx          Then look for this link "Install Debugging Tools for Windows as a Standalone Component (from Windows SDK)"

Comment: and after you install it on the same page above download symbol package for your specific OS. Once installed open it up. go to file>>>open crash dump and point to where the minidump file is located, wait a bit for it to load up and viola it should give you an idea of the what driver or issue was causing the problem. 99.999% of the time the driver that's listed is the cuplprit, the other .001% of the time, that driver failed as a symptom of something else, but at least you have a direction to go down in your troubleshooting.

Comment: OOo i should have read your question better my apologies, if the problem is infact with your MQ connection it won't find the bug with that. This will just tell you if MQ is the problem or if perhaps something else is causing it to crash. I should have read slower *derp* lol

Answer (score 0):

dnx: Do you mean disabling ipv6 on the remote machine or on your own local machine?

Comment: I received a hotfix (KB2840622) from MS in September. Sorry for the delay informing it here.. The hot fix solved the issue.. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2840622

Comment: @jha, thanks for pointing to the hotfix, seems fixing my issue of BSOD on Windows Server 2012.